# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: f#, type-providers

I can not use the SqlType provider due to an issue with Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.
I am using a minimal program with .NET 4.7.2 and F# 4.7.0.0.
My Nuget packages contain a reference to:

> package id="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" version="1.0.0"
>   targetFramework="net472"
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error FS3033  The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider'
>   reported an error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
>   Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information. Details: 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or
>   one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht
>   finden.   TestSqlProvider C:\Users\weism\source\repos\TestSqlProvider\TestSqlProvider\Program.fs  9   Active

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: The English translation of "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden" is "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: Are you using .net core? If so does the command `dotnet restore` fix anything?

Comment: If  it's still an issue, can you post csproj of this app?

Answer (score 45):

For me, installing the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (Nuget package) fixed the issue.

Comment: Just the right Answer, Installing this to the project which when compiled and ran gives the problem, solves it :)

Answer (score 14):

This error also happens when you try using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` v5 in a dotnet core v3.1 project.
To resolve, down-version `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to latest v3 version.

Comment: Or upgrade .NET Core to v5. =)

Comment: This worked for me.. after clearing all nuget cache from package manager setting

Answer (score 13):

For **.Net Core**, This problem basically occurs, when we use layered architecture. Just make sure the version of **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** should be same in all project, wherever it is used.

Comment: In my case was almost that. 
I had installed **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory** version 5.0.7  which depends on *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore*. So, as you mentioned, as soon as all the projects had the same version the issue was solved.

Answer (score 11):

I don't use Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces at all in my .NET 4.8 project. Some library depends on version  1.0.0.0. I resolved the issue using a binding redirect:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll 5 was copied to **Bin** after build.

Comment: I needed this for XrmToolbox. Except I had to bind for Version 7.0.0.0

Answer (score 3):

I think you update package in one layer. 
for me  i worked in project with three layers (api, AdminTool, Data) the AdminTool Layer had a reference to Data Layer i updated all packages in AdminTool only so i had this error i update package also in data layer and api layer so the problem solved.
I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

My Entity Framework Core just needed upgraded
  TO

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unique single version of that dll. Another step would be to add a binding redirect in the app.config as told in the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your installed nuget packages---
If version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and your .net project is different then it can be a problem.
Example - If EntityFrameworkCore is at v5.1.5 or higher & your project dotnet core v3.1 project, this can be the issue.

To solve,

1. down-version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to equal version of project such as v3 version. to down version click on tool in visual studio -->Nuget Package Manager--> Manage Nuget package for Solutions --> click on installed ---> select nuget package which you want to downgrade --> click on uninstall and then select the same nuget package and then install version 3.1.5 or relevent package.

or

2. Install Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces (Nuget package)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the **Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces** assembly via NuGet did everything it needed to do, including adding the `bindingRedirect` entries in the appropriate config files.

I also did all the other hygienics. I cleaned my solution, deleted the bin and obj directory entries, and also cleaned my localhost deploy locations.

However, I still got this error. I reviewed the output (my application is a .NET 4.8 MVC Web application, so the web page showed the error log in detail), and I found that it was failing on loading **SimpleInjector**.

I updated **SimpleInjector** to the latest version via NuGet and that fixed my error.

Unfortunately, I didn't keep a copy of the error page, so I can't show you what I saw, but the bottom line is to examine the output or log in detail, see if you can find where the application is attempting to load the assembly that is failing, and update that assembly that appears to be calling the load.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by removing `<Private>True</Private>` from csproj for `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`. Just reinstall this NuGet package

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart my production server, which is also my web server for several websites, among other things.
After the restart, I now have a new, different error `Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source...`
What a nightmare NuGet package management is.